# Installing magento in a sub-folder

Tags: upgrade, installation

I currently have a live website (Say `www.abc123.com`)in my folder "`public_html/abc123.com`". It is currently on magento 1.7.0.2 and I have been told that to upgrade to 1.9.1 is sometimes complicated. So my question is am I able to install a fresh new magento 1.9.1 in a sub folder (`public_html/abc123.com/magento`), work on it, then once it is done and ready to go, I simply point my domain to the sub-folder. This way, I won't get any downtime as well. I also understand that my database and order history will start all over.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You have to make sure to use another database and base_urls to the subfolder

Comment: Hi I just did a test with one not live website. I installed the magento in the magento folder with a new database, went to my cpanel - add on domains and changed the document root to "public_html/abc123.com/magento". However when I go to my browser to type www.abc123.com. It redirects to me to www.abc123.com/magento/. Then I get Index of /magento, Parent Directory, Apache Server at www.abc123.com Port 80.

Comment: You shouldn't change the document root of the domain "abc123.com". Revert that and it should work.

Comment: ok but if I revert it back, when my customer types www.abc123.com, it goes to the old website. Only if they type www.abc123.com/magento, then they will get to the new one.

Comment: correct. Isn't that what you wanted? When you are ready to launch, you change the baseurl of the new shop and either, move your code to the abc.com directory or change the webroot.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to go change the base URL in my database to the original http://www.abc123.com/ and clear my VAR/CAC folder.